# How to handle user profile route

Tags: angular, firebase

I am building a user-list component to list all users and user-detail components to show an individual user.

However, only the admin should be able to see all users, and a user can only see their own profile.

```
{
    path: 'users'... some can activate guard here that checks admin role?
},
{
    path: 'users/:id'...
}
```

I guess my question is, is this the right approach since the details route is a child of users, and only admins can see that route or is there a better pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides several guards to do this. You can use `canActivate` as illustrated in [CanActivate: requiring authentication](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication) or `canLoad` as illustrated in [CanLoad Guard: guarding unauthorized loading of feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules). Implement your conditional logic in one of them.